# Google Play Game Services Cannot access Leaderboard "Attempt to access application x from application y"

Tags: android, google-play-games

I created a new Google Play Game Services game (12 digit client id y) and INCORRECTLY specified the leaderboard in my  definition as being the one belonging to an existing game (12 digit client id x).

I spotted the error, fixed it, and published the game. A while later, I noticed that game x was unable to access its own leaderboard. The full text of the error message is :

E/MultiDataOperation(nnn): Attempt to access application x from application y . The error as seen by the user is displayed here [image: leaderboard problem]

I recreated the error on an emulator. I checked my definitions, and wrote out my  definitions to the console and verified that I was using the correct client id, package name and leaderboard id.

It looks as though Google control blocks / indexes / databases or whatever have erroneously associated my leaderboard from game x with game y so that game x is now unable to access it. I want to delete and redefine my resources for game x, but since it is published, I do not know what to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am posting my own answer because there is a chance that this might help someone else out. Again, I emphasise that the original error was mine - when I first used game y, I INCORRECTLY specified a leaderboard belonging to game X.

I simply created a new leaderboard for game X (it is not possible to delete the existing one because it had already been published) and users are able to access that. I updated my resources definition for the leaderboard and uploaded the new apk.  It is a workaround to what I see as an error attributable to Google, but it works for me.